# htaccess - prettify a minified version

Tags: .htaccess, notepad

I have an `.htaccess` with a good number of redirects. After being modified by a Wordpress plugin, it appears that all the rules have been concatenated; at least no line breaks are visible.

**Edit:**

This seems to be a problem **only** when the file is opened in Windows Notepad. When I open it with Sublime, or even copy a snippet to here, it shows the line breaks. I toggled line-wrap in Notepad, but it still treats the whole thing as a single line.

Comment: Are you sure the htaccess file itself has been minified? And not stuff like you scripts?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Where I had each rewrite rule on a separate line, the plugin can and eliminated the link breaks, essentially stringing together all my rules. While they still work, I want them back to one per line. Not sure if 'minified' is the right word here.

Comment: Apache's directives are delimited by newlines, if you have all your rewrite rules in a single line, you'd get a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems to be a problem only when the file is opened in Windows Notepad.

This is because the file has non-Windows line endings (\r\n), but probably Linux line endings (\n). Windows Notepad only recognizes Windows line endings.
You can use Notepad++ to convert line endings, but this does not stop Wordpress to apply the linux line endings, obviously.